# Different size on nav-bar on different pages

Tags: html, css

If you check the site im building http://pripper.github.io/obk/index.html
So can you see that the nav bar is changing size on different pages and I dont know why it does it. Please someone help me out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Hi Johan. A quick look on your site shows that your `font-family` is changing between the pages. Perhaps you need to look at your stylesheets?

Comment: You haven't included same css files in all pages.. Some page has `w3.css` file while other haven't. In index page: `img {margin-bottom: -5px}` while on other page is missing, so the menu under your header image looks different

Comment: ty that fixed the height

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have included w3.css on all pages apart from index, this is applying a negative margin to your logo/image.

[image]